# How to create sidenote helper macro which handles notes inside captions

Tags: captions, conditionals, marginpar, sidenotes

I am trying to write a simple macro that will add a sidenote which will inline the note if it is added to a caption.  To do this I am testing if I am in inner mode, but the test doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone suggest what I should do?  Here is an example of the failing code.  The key is my definition of `\addnote` on line 9 which should either add a sidenote or just add in the text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}


\def\mysidenote#1#2{\color{#1}\marginpar{\footnotesize\setstretch{0.9}\raggedright\color{#1} #2}}
\def\addnote#1#2{\ifinner{\color{#1} #2}\else \mysidenote{#1}{#2} \fi}
%\def\addnote#1#2{\mysidenote{#1}{#2}}

\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.5in},top=1in,left=.75in,marginparwidth=2.5in,, marginparsep=.1in,includeall]{geometry}
\begin{document}
here is some text\addnote{red}{the first note} and some more text\addnote{blue}{the second note} and blah blah.
\begin{figure}
a figure
\caption{figure caption\addnote{green}{note in caption}}
\end{figure}
and some more text after the figure.
\end{document}
```

When the above code is run through pdflatex, I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20 \end{document}
```

Note, that if I don't put the `\ifinner` test in the definition of `\addnote`, then instead I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17 ...e caption\addnote{green}{note in caption}}
```

So, the test is doing something, just not what I want it to do.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99885) seems to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter   
\newcommand\ifInFloat[2]{\@ifundefined{@captype}{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother

\def\mysidenote#1#2{\color{#1}\marginpar{\footnotesize\setstretch{0.9}\raggedright\color{#1} #2}}
\def\addnote#1#2{\ifInFloat{\color{#1} #2}{\mysidenote{#1}{#2}}}

\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.5in},top=1in,left=.75in,marginparwidth=2.5in,, marginparsep=.1in,includeall]{geometry}
\begin{document}
here is some text\addnote{red}{the first note} and some more text\addnote{blue}{the second note} and blah blah.
\begin{figure}
a figure
\caption{figure caption 
\protect\addnote{green}{note in caption}
}
\end{figure}
and some more text after the figure. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!